# Parameters and Loops in snippets

Tags: sublimetext2, code-snippets

I would like to make a snippet that makes an HTML table.

Here are some examples of things to type :

table name address city
   - table team wins losses draws
   - table views clicks clickthrough

This is what I want it to output : a table with a columns for each of the fields (with 'table' triggering the snippet).

I'd also like to run these field names through a function to transform them (for example to field names - "First Name" -> 'first_name'.

Is this possible? How would I do it?

Comment: I didn't get the first question but "First Name" -> "first_name" is CaseConversion plugins' job

Comment: I mean I want to type 'table city address state' and have it expand into an html table where the row says 'city' 'address' and 'state' in each cell.

Comment: From what I've seen, you can't do loops in snippets, you could in a python plugin, however.  But, there is probably a better way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly what you want, but I would go with [Emmet](http://docs.emmet.io/) (here is a handy [cheet sheet](http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/)).  There is a [Sublime package](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime) available, so it's easy to install.  It might be a little overwhelming at first, but once you start to use it, you will get the hang of it and it will speed up your html/css production.

Type `table>tr*3>th` and hit <kbd>tab</kbd> at the end.  This will produce:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then you can tab to the `th`s to type in your column headers.